# Finding rainbow cycle in digraph colored with $\log n$ colors

Tags: graphs, colorings

> Given a directed graph with $n$ vertices, and $k=\log n$, we are given a coloring of the vertices with $k$ colors.
>
> Describe an algorithm determining if there exists a simple cycle in $G$ of length $k$ visiting exactly one vertex of each color.
>
> Time complexity should be $O(n^3)$.

I couldn't think of any efficient solution.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use dynamic programming. For each vertex $v$ and color subset $S$, calculate whether there is a simple path, ending at $v$, and including exactly the colors in $S$. Details left to you.

The main trick here is that we can be sure that the path being constructed is simple since all vertices in it have different colors. We can apply the same idea to *uncolored* graphs by choosing a random coloring. This is known as [color-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-coding), an idea of Alon, Yuster and Zwick with wide applicability.